# Printf in C prints ffffffe1 instead of e1

Tags: c

I am very much confused, I have a small program where I am printing the value at different address location.

```
int main ()
{
 // unsigned int x = 0x15711056;
  unsigned int x = 0x15b11056;
  char *c = (char*) &x;

  printf ("*c is: 0x%x\n", *c);
  printf("size of %d\n", sizeof(x));
  printf("Value at first address %x\n", *(c+0));
  printf("Value at second address %x\n", *(c+1));
  printf("Value at third address %x\n", *(c+2));
  printf("Value at fourth address %x\n", *(c+3));
```

For the commented unsigned int x the printf values are as expected i.e.

```
  printf("Value at first address %x\n", *(c+0)) = 56
  printf("Value at second address %x\n", *(c+1))= 10
  printf("Value at third address %x\n", *(c+2))= 71
  printf("Value at fourth address %x\n", *(c+3))= 15
```

But for un-commented int x why I am getting below result for *(c+2) It should be **b1** not **ffffffb1**. Please help me to understand this I am running this on an online IDE https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler. My PC is i7 intel.

```
  printf("Value at first address %x\n", *(c+0)) = 56
  printf("Value at second address %x\n", *(c+1))= 10
  printf("Value at third address %x\n", *(c+2))= ffffffb1
  printf("Value at fourth address %x\n", *(c+3))= 15
```

Comment: Not sure if `char *c = (char*) &x; ` is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi sjsam : I did not get you what you asked?
char *c = (char*) &x // here I am assigning the address of x to a pointer of type char.

Comment: When you pass a `char` to `printf()`, it undergoes integer promotions to an `int`.  With your compiler, plain `char` is a signed type, so the value 0xB1 is negative and is promoted to a negative integer value.  You then print it as if it were unsigned, which means it has leading hex `FF` bytes (because of the way two's complement arithmetic works).

Comment: Enable **compiler warnings**, that will help the compiler help you fix undefined behavior in your code. Specifically using type-mismatched format specifiers in your `printf` strings will kill you. e.g., `printf("size of %d\n", sizeof(x));` => *Undefined Behavior*. For answer to your specific question, look up *sign extension* for signed integer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int x = 0x15b11056; /*lets say starting address of x is 0x100 */
char *c = (char*) &x; /** c is char pointer i.e at a time it can fetch 1 byte and it points to 0x100 **/
```

`x` looks like as below

```
  ------------------------------------------------------
  | 0001 0101  |  1011 0001  |  0001 0000  |  0101 0110 |
   ------------------------------------------------------
0x104         0x103         0x102         0x101        0x100
                                                        x
                                                        c
```

Next, when you are doing `*(c+2));` Lets expand it

```
*(c+2)) = *(0x100 + 2*1) /** increment by 1 byte */
           = *(0x102)
           =  1011 0001 (in binary) Notice here that sign bit is 1 
              means sign bit is going to copy to remaining bytes
```

As you are printing in `%x` format which expects `unsigned type` but `c` is of `signed` byte,`sign bit` gets copied into remaining bytes.

for `*(c+2)` input will be looks like

```
 0000 0000  |  0000 0000  |  0000 0000  |  1011 0001
                                                |
                                            sign bit is one so this bit will be copied into remaining bytes, resultant will look like below
 1111 1111  |  1111 1111   |  1111 1111  |  1011 0001  
  f     f       f    f          f    f        b   1
```

I explained particular part which you had doubt, I hope it helps.

Comment: The `unsigned int x = 0x15b11056` part is confusing here, I thought `x` represented an an address here.. Further down, the op goes on taking `&x` and then tries to dereference the `char` values there.. This part is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The value is signed as `0xB1` is `10110001` in binary, you need to use an `unsigned char` pointer:

```
unsigned char *c = (unsigned char*) &x;
```

Your code would work for any bytes up to `0x7F`.

Answer (score 2):

`c` is a `signed char`, `0xB1` (which is signed) is `1011 0001`, you see that
the most significant bit is 1, so it's a negative number.

When you pass `*(c+2)` to `printf`, it gets promoted to an `int` which is
signed. Sign extension fills the rest of the bits with the same value as the
most significant bit from your `char`, which is 1. At this point `printf`
gets `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 0001`.

`%x` in `printf` prints it as an `unsigned int`, thus it prints `0xFFFFFFB1`.

You have to declare your pointer as an `unsigned char`.

```
unsigned char *c = (unsigned char*) &x;
```